# Event handlers for object variables VB, VS

Tags: vb.net

Working with a Windows.Forms.Form from the VS designer I can use the KeyDown event when it is fired on a form or on child control (I am interested in RichTextBox). But I want to use the event on a variable type RichTextBox, say:

```
Dim rtbx as new RichTextBox 
Sub rtbx_OnKeyDown(sender as object, e as KeyEventArgs) Handles rtbx.KeyDown
```

VS does not understand this. There is a method OnKeyDown listed in the ObjectBrowser, which is associated with the grandparent Control class of the RichTextBox, but I have not found any way to call this method. Examples on Microsoft VB documentation show only code looking like one copied from Form.vb class.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to attach event handlers in VB. One is to use the `WithEvents` keyword on a field and the `Handles` keyword on a method, e.g.

```vb
Private WithEvents myRichTextBox As RichTextBox
```

and:

```vb
Private Sub myRichTextBox_KeyDown(sender as object, e as KeyEventArgs) Handles myRichTextBox.KeyDown
```

That's how it works when you add controls in the designer and then have the IDE generate the event handler. If you look in the designer code file, you'll see a field declared for each control and component you added and each declared `WithEvents`. If you do that then the event handler remains connected to the field, even if you change the value of the field.

The other option is to use the `AddHandler` keyword. This is what you must do when attaching an event handler via a local variable, because they obviously cannot be declared `WithEvents`, e.g.

```vb
Private Sub myRichTextBox_KeyDown(sender as object, e as KeyEventArgs)
```

Note there's no `Handles` clause on the method. Then:

```vb
Dim myRichTextBox As New RichTextBox

'...

AddHandler myRichTextBox.KeyDown, AddressOf myRichTextBox_KeyDown
```

That event handler will remain attached to the object and, while it is not strictly necessary in some cases, it is good practice to always detach the event handler when you're done with the it:

```vb
RemoveHandler myRichTextBox.KeyDown, AddressOf myRichTextBox_KeyDown
```

You need a reference to the object in order to do that, so you might use a field in order to store that. If there will only be one object, you may as well declare the field `WithEvents` and use `Handles`. If there may be multiple objects then you can use a list and then loop through that list to detach the event handlers.

Comment: If you use `RemoveHandler` I would **strongly** recommend to also use `Option Strict On`.  Without it, the "relaxed delegate convention" will allow creation of subscribe-only delegates on signature mismatches that are impossible to unsubscribe (that is, your RemoveHandler will have no effect).

Comment: Thanks, 'With Events' works OK

Comment: @Craig, I would recommend using `Option Strict On` all the time regardless.

Comment: I agree that it's always a good idea, I just wanted to make the point that it's particularly important in this case---a lot of the things that `Option Strict On` calls out can be accessed by activating certain individual warnings or errors, but in my experience the delegate signature issue could only be diagnosed with `Option Strict On`.

Comment: @StanislawSemczuk, in an answer resolved you issue then please accept so everyone can see that without having to read the comments.